# Могут ли быть вредоносные драйвера (теоретический вопрос)

Tags: безопасность, защита, ядро, драйвер

Здравствуйте. Мне интересно, вот есть обычные программы и драйвера,обычные программы висят как правило на каких-то кольцах безопасности, точно не помню их номера, но точно не на 0, а есть драйвер которые висят на 0 уровне. Так вот сам вопрос, почему драйверам система доверяет висеть на 0 уровне, они что не смогут не чего плохого что ли сделать на этом уровне и защищают ли от таких драйверов антивирусы (и если можно то как)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Драйвера могут быть и вредоносными, но что-бы получить цифровую подпись, то нужно постараться и потратить деньги. Сейчас, что-бы установить драйвер без цифровой подписи нужно повозиться: "Диагностика -> Перезагрузка и затем "Отключить обязательную проверку подписи драйверов". Довольно геморно. А то что драйвера работают на CORE уровне, то так исторически сложилось (прерывания int 33h, и другие, работают только на 0lvl)

Answer (score 2):

Вредоносными быть драйвера могут и такие есть.

С чего вы решили, что доверяет? У драйверов обязательная цифровая подпись, которая во-первых стоит 300 долларов, во-вторых может попасть в черный список при жалобе.

Вообще, если все ваше знакомство с неким сабжем сводится к беглому листанию первой попавшейся книжонки или статьи в вики и при этом вы что-то решаете по данному сабжу, то оно вполне может оказаться не так. Особенно, если статья времен Win 9k.

Антивирусы - да, защищают.

Comment: Извините за глупый вопрос, а без цифровой подписи, что драйвер совсем без шансов поставить ?

Comment: @alex-rudenkiy На всякий случай - крякнуть защиту в ОС, как и любом другом очень популярном софте, связано с проблемой - с ее постоянными обновлениями, которые быстро вернут все как было и драйвер заблокируется. Нужно либо следить за обновлениями 24/7 и быстро выпускать новую версию кряка, либо еще и ломать механизм обновления (многие вам даже спасибо скажут :) ), либо надеяться, что у вашего виру... установщика хватит мозгов чтобы корректно крякать обновленные файлы, не выводя их из строя.